# Javascript date offset

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a filter's page for a report. On that page, I have radio inputs where a user can select quick report options that auto populate the filters. There is one field that has stumped me. I am able to to successfully offset the date field by the year, and by the month, but when I try to offset by the day, it will do the follow:

Seeing that today is 2/5/16, and I try to offset by 7 days, it will calculate to 2/29/16. It counts the correct number of days, but fails to go back to January and present 1/29/16. Here is my javascript:

```
function dateDayOffset(theDay) {
    var now = new Date();
    var m=now.getMonth()+1;
    now.setDate(now.getDate() + theDay );
    var d=now.getDate();
    var y=now.getFullYear();
    var  dayOffset = m + "/" + d + "/" + y;
    return((zeroPadDate(dayOffset)));
};
```

And here is my where I am using the jQuery in my filters page:

```
$("#ToDate").val(dateDayOffset(-7));
```

Comment: do the modifications...then get values. You are getting month value from current date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, when it comes to dates, you're better off using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to handle stuff like this. Other issues such as 28/29/30/31 day months will affect you if you do it manually.

You can use `moment().subtract(7, 'days')` to accomplish what you want.

But regarding your code, it seems the issue you're having is you're getting the month *before* you change the date. Move that code after the line where you change the date and it should work fine.

```
function dateDayOffset(theDay) {
    var now = new Date();
    now.setDate(now.getDate() + theDay );
    var m=now.getMonth()+1;
    var d=now.getDate();
    var y=now.getFullYear();
    var  dayOffset = m + "/" + d + "/" + y;
    return((zeroPadDate(dayOffset)));
};
```

Comment: I saw your answer right before you modified it, and that was a good catch.

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you so much for your help!